# How to optimize multiple left-joins SQL SELECT-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, query-optimization

Situation:

We have a database "base1" ~ 6 million lines of data, which shows the actual customer purchases and the day of purchase + the parameters of this purchase.

```
CREATE TABLE base1 (
User_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
PurchaseDate date,
Parameter1 int,
Parameter2 int,
...
ParameterK int );
```

And also another database "base2" ~ 90 million lines of data, which actually shows the same thing, but instead of the day of purchase, a weekly section is used (for example: all weeks for 4 years for each client - if there was no purchase for N week, the client is still shown).

```
CREATE TABLE base2 (
Users_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
Week_start date ,
Week_end date,
Parameter1 int,
Parameter2 int,
...
ParameterN int );
```

The task to do the following query:

```
-- a = base1 , b , wb%% = base2
--create index idx_uid_purch_date on base1(Users_ID,Purchasedate);
SELECT a.Users_id
-- Checking whether the client will make a purchase in next week and the purchase will be bought on condition
,iif(b.Users_id is not null,1,0) as User_will_buy_next_week
,iif(b.Users_id is not null and b.Parameter1 = 1,1,0) as User_will_buy_on_Condition1
--   about 12 similar iif-conditions
,iif(b.Users_id is not null and (b.Parameter1 = 1 and b.Parameter12 = 1),1,0) 
as User_will_buy_on_Condition13

-- checking on the fact of purchase in the past month, 2 months ago, 2.5 months, etc.
,iif(wb1m.Users_id is null,0,1) as was_buy_1_month_ago
,iif(wb2m.Users_id is null,0,1) as was_buy_2_month_ago
,iif(wb25m.Users_id is null,0,1) as was_buy_25_month_ago
,iif(wb3m.Users_id is null,0,1) as was_buy_3_month_ago
,iif(wb6m.Users_id is null,0,1) as was_buy_6_month_ago
,iif(wb1y.Users_id is null,0,1) as was_buy_1_year_ago

 ,a.[Week_start]
 ,a.[Week_end]

 into base3
 FROM base2 a 

 -- Join for User_will_buy
 left join base1 b
 on a.Users_id =b.Users_id and 
 cast(b.[PurchaseDate] as date)>=DATEADD(dd,7,cast(a.[Week_end] as date)) 
 and cast(b.[PurchaseDate] as date)<=DATEADD(dd,14,cast(a.[Week_end] as date))

 -- Joins for was_buy
 left join base1  wb1m
 on a.Users_id =wb1m.Users_id 
 and cast(wb1m.[PurchaseDate] as date)>=DATEADD(dd,-30-4,cast(a.[Week_end] as date)) 
 and cast(wb1m.[PurchaseDate] as date)<=DATEADD(dd,-30+4,cast(a.[Week_end] as date))

/* 4 more similar joins where different values are added in 
DATEADD (dd, %%, cast (a. [Week_end] as date))
to check on the fact of purchase for a certain period */

 left outer join base1 wb1y
 on a.Users_id =wb1y.Users_id and 
 cast(wb1y.[PurchaseDate] as date)>=DATEADD(dd,-365-4,cast(a.[Week_end] as date)) 
 and cast(wb1y.[PurchaseDate] as date)<=DATEADD(dd,-365+5,cast(a.[Week_end] as date))
```

Because of the huge number of Joins and rather big databases - this script runs for about **24 hours**, which is incredibly long.

Main time, as the execution plan shows, is spent on "Merge Join" and view the rows of the table from base1 and base2, and insert the data into another base3 table.

Question: Is it possible to optimize this query so it works faster?

Perhaps using one Join instead or something.

Help please, I'm not that smart enough :(

Thanx everybody for your answers!

UPD: Maybe use of different type of joins (merge, loop, or hash) may help me, but can't really check this theory. Maybe someone can tell me whether it's right or wrong ;)

Comment: The "problem" is that syntax like `DATEADD(dd, 7, CAST(a.[Week_end] AS date))` in your `ON` aren't SARGable, meaning that no indexes can be used to help the data engine has to perform a full scan of your tables.

Comment: To expand on what @Larnu said, your first step would be to rewrite the joins so that they do not use functions. As the reason is the function needs to be run against every row in the table *before* SQL can compare and filter. Rather than only comparing the rows which meet the JOIN criteria--it will do them all, every time. And it can't use an index, which would speed up that process. Think of it this way, you've got a book of dates with millions of rows. Do you a) translate the date and then compare to the book or b) translate the entire book first?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers , now I even know what SARGable means  But still do not understand how to rewrite them using no function at all (I’ve deleted all “casts”, but still DATEADD remained )

Comment: Are you sure the query does what you want it to do? What exactly do you want to achieve? You select 90 million rows from base2 without any filter, then you outer join date ranges of base1, so you end up with something between 90 million and 4.4 billion result rows, or so I've calculated.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ouput for this query is every customer data on every week with additional information about whether customer bought something last month, or last year + will customer buy something next week depending on purchase_history which is base1

Comment: Okay, that would be 90 million result rows then. That's already a lot and I wonder whether you actually need this much data in your result. What is it for? Nobody will actually scroll through a report 90 million rows long. And who wants to know whether in a week two years ago a purchase occurred in the week following, I guess. So you might be able to reduce the desired result substantially somehow.

Comment: Anyway, starting with the 90 million base2 rows, you are joining single days. Let's take `left join base1 b ...` for instance: You are joining days of one week later. If there is only one day (or even no day at all) for a customer in that range then you stay with the base2 row. If there are seven days, however, then you've already have the base2 row seven-fold in your results. Hence the possible 4.4. billion result rows. You'd need an aggregation or `EXIST` clause here to stay with 90 million rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Unfortunatly, I need all data to solve problem. Yet, I've understood what you said, and will try to reduce output data by aggregation. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have all 90 million base2 rows in your result, each with additional information on base1 data. So, what the DBMS must do is a full table scan on base2 and quickly find related rows in base1.

The query with `EXISTS` clauses would look something like this:

```
select
  b2.users_id,
  b2.week_start,
  b2.week_end,
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from base1 b1 
    where b1.users_id = b2.users_id
    and b1.purchasedate between dateadd(day, 7, cast(b2.week_end as date))
                            and dateadd(day, 14, cast(b2.week_end as date))´
  ) then 1 else 0 end as user_will_buy_next_week,
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from base1 b1 
    where b1.users_id = b2.users_id
    and b1.parameter1 = 1
    and b1.purchasedate between dateadd(day, 7, cast(b2.week_end as date))
                            and dateadd(day, 14, cast(b2.week_end as date))´
  ) then 1 else 0 end as user_will_buy_on_condition1,
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from base1 b1 
    where b1.users_id = b2.users_id
    and b1.parameter1 = 1
    and b1.parameter2 = 1
    and b1.purchasedate between dateadd(day, 7, cast(b2.week_end as date))
                            and dateadd(day, 14, cast(b2.week_end as date))´
  ) then 1 else 0 end as user_will_buy_on_condition13,
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from base1 b1 
    where b1.users_id = b2.users_id
    and b1.purchasedate between dateadd(day, -30-4, cast(b2.week_end as date))
                            and dateadd(day, -30+4, cast(b2.week_end as date))´
  ) then 1 else 0 end as was_buy_1_month_ago,
  ...
from base2 b2;
```

We can easily see that this will take a long time, because all conditions must be checked per base2 row. That is 9 million times 7 lookups. The only thing we can do about this is to provide an index, hoping the query will benefit from it.

```
create index idx1 on base1 (users_id, purchasedate, parameter1, parameter2);
```

We can add more indexes, so the DBMS can choose between them on selectivity. Later we can check whether they are used and drop them in case they aren't.

```
create index idx2 on base1 (users_id, parameter1, purchasedate);
create index idx3 on base1 (users_id, parameter1, parameter2, purchasedate);
create index idx4 on base1 (users_id, parameter2, parameter1, purchasedate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `base1` table stores information about the current week purchases.

If that is true, in the query conditions of joins you could ignore `[PurchaseDate]` parameter, replacing it with the current date constant instead. In that case your `DATEADD` functions will be applied to the current date and will be constants in the conditions of joins:

```
left join base1 b
on a.Users_id =b.Users_id and 
DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE())>=a.[Week_end] 
and DATEADD(day,-14,GETDATE())<=a.[Week_end]
```

To have the query above running correctly you should limit `b.[PurchaseDate]` to the current day.

Then you could run another query, for the purchases made yesterday, and all `DATEADD` constants in join conditions corrected by `-1`

And so on, up to 7 queries, or whatever timespan the `base1` table covers.

You could also implement grouping of `[PurchaseDate]` values by days, recalculate constants and make all of that in a single query, but I'm not ready to spend time creating it myself. :)

Comment: Sorry for not answering for a long time.
Unfortunatly your assumption is wrong for that base1 , cause it stores retrospective information for past several years. But it's still was very useful for my recent tracks, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have recurring argument such as `DATEADD(dd,-30-4,cast(a.[Week_end] as date))` for example, to make it SARGable you can create an index on it (SQL Server can't). Postgres can do this:

```
create index ix_base2__34_days_ago on base2(DATEADD(dd,-30-4, cast([Week_end] as date)))
```

Then an expression like the following would be SARGable as index on `DATEADD(dd,-30-4, cast([Week_end]))` would be utilized by your database, hence a condition like the following will be fast if you have an index like on the example above.

```
and cast(wb1m.[PurchaseDate] as date) >= DATEADD(dd,-30-4,cast(a.[Week_end] as date))
```

Note that casting PurchaseDate to date yields a SARGable expression, despite `cast` looking like a function, as SQL Server has special handling of datetime to date, an index on datetime field is SARGable even you search on datetime field partially (the date part only). Similar to partial expression `like`, `where lastname LIKE 'Mc%'`, that expression is SARGable even if an index is for the whole lastname field. I digress.

To somewhat achieve the index on expression on SQL Server, you can create a computed column on that expression.., e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE base2 (
  Users_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  Week_start date ,
  Week_end date,
  Parameter1 int,
  Parameter2 int,
  Thirty4DaysAgo as DATEADD(dd,-30-4, cast([Week_end] as date))
)
```

..and then create index on that column:

```
create index ix_base2_34_days_ago on base2(Thirty4DaysAgo)
```

Then change your expression to:

```
and cast(wb1m.[PurchaseDate] as date) >= a.Thirty4DaysAgo
```

That's what I would recommend before, change the old expression to use the computed column. However, upon further searching, it looks like you can just retain your original code, as SQL Server can intelligently match an expression to the computed column, and if you have an index on that column, your expression would be SARGable. Thus your DBA can optimize things behind the scenes and your original code would run optimized without requiring any changes on your code. So no need to change the following, and it will be SARGable (granted that your DBA created a computed column for `dateadd(recurring parameters here)` expression, and applied index on it) :

```
and cast(wb1m.[PurchaseDate] as date) >= DATEADD(dd,-30-4,cast(a.[Week_end] as date))
```

The only downside (when compared to Postgres) is you still have the dangling computed column on your table when using SQL Server :)

Good read: https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/01/sql-servers-year-function-and-index-performance/

Comment: Thank you a lot! That should probably solve the case!